# 非同期処理での実行される順番について

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, swift2

AWSののdynamoDBを用いて、`loadUser()`データベースに上がってある画像のURLを持ってきて、`downloadImage()`で画像をダウンロードして、`addImage()`で`scrollView`に追加するようなことをしています。
しかし、`downloadImage()`内でダウンロードされた順番(loadCounter)を出力してみると
0
2
1
などのように出力されて、順番通りに出力されませんでした。
非同期処理で順番通りにダウンロードするにはどこを変更したらいいでしょうか。お願いします。

```
import UIKit
import AWSCore
import AWSS3
import AWSDynamoDB

class LoadViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate {


    var loadImages:[UIImage] = []
    var loadItems:[DDBTableRow] = []

    var userId:String?
    var userName:String?
    var pagniatedOutput: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.scrollView.delegate = self

        self.userName = defaults.stringForKey("userName")
        self.userId = defaults.stringForKey("userId")


        loadUser()

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func addImage(image:UIImage)
    {
        let sheight = self.scrollView.frame.height
        let swidth = self.scrollView.frame.width

        loadImages.append(image)
        let myImageView = UIImageView()
        myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(swidth * CGFloat(loadImages.count-1), 0, swidth, sheight)
        myImageView.image = image
        myImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        scrollView.addSubview(myImageView)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(swidth * CGFloat(loadImages.count), sheight)

    }



    func loadUser()
    {
        let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()

        let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
        queryExpression.hashKeyValues = userId
        queryExpression.scanIndexForward = false
        var loadCounter:Int = 0
        dynamoDBObjectMapper .query(DDBTableRow.self, expression: queryExpression) .continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            if (task.error != nil) {
                print("Error: \(task.error)")

            } else {
                if (task.result != nil) {
                    self.pagniatedOutput = task.result as? AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput

                    for item in (self.pagniatedOutput?.items)!
                    {
                        let tableRow = item as! DDBTableRow

                        print(tableRow.Date)
                        self.downloadImage(tableRow.ImageURL!,loadCounter: loadCounter)
                        self.loadItems.append(tableRow)
                        loadCounter += 1

                    }
                }
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToMainSegue", sender: self)
            }
            return nil
        })
    }

    func downloadImage(S3DownloadKeyName: String,loadCounter:Int){

        var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock?

        let queue:dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("com.gologo13.gcd", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

        let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression()
                expression.downloadProgress = {(task: AWSS3TransferUtilityTask, bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) in
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        let progress = Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)
                        NSLog("Progress is: %f",progress)
                    })
                }


        completionHandler = { (task, location, data, error) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if ((error) != nil){
                    NSLog("Failed with error")
                    NSLog("Error: %@",error!)
                }
                else{
                    print(Success)
                    self.addImage(UIImage(data: data!)!)
                    //loadCounterのデバック
                    print(loadCounter)
                    //loadCounterの出力される値が順番通りにならない
                }
            })
        }

        let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.defaultS3TransferUtility()

        transferUtility.downloadToURL(nil, bucket: S3BucketName, key: S3DownloadKeyName, expression: expression, completionHander: completionHandler).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
            if let error = task.error {
                NSLog("Error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
                //  self.statusLabel.text = "Failed"
            }
            if let exception = task.exception {
                NSLog("Exception: %@",exception.description);
                //  self.statusLabel.text = "Failed"
            }
            if let _ = task.result {
                //    self.statusLabel.text = "Starting Download"
                NSLog("Download Starting!")
                // Do something with uploadTask.
            }
            return nil;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 非同期で並列に全てリクエストするんじゃなくて、別途関数作って再起処理にすると良いんじゃないかと思います。

Comment: 非同期処理というのは、処理の間の時間的前後関係を合せない(非・同期)という事です。だから、処理が終わった順で結果を処理すると、順序はばらばらになります。解決の方針は２つあります。1つ目は処理を一つずつ順に実行する事で結果の順序を保証する方法（直列処理）で、並列実行による処理速度向上は諦める。2つ目は処理が終わった後に結果の順序を並び替えてから返す方法です。

Answer (score 1):

取得したデータの

> for(var i=0; i < image_list.length; i++){
>   image.src=url[i];
>   }
>   のiを
>   sortしてみてはどうですか。

Answer (score 0):

`.addImage`の中で配列の最後にイメージを追加していくのではなく、配列に`insert:image, atIndex:loadCounter`にして再描画する仕組みにしてみてはいかがでしょうか